# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error JDeveloper 12c

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdeveloper

I am trying to call a java stored procedure in java application. I am using ORACLE database and JDeveloper.

I am getting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. I have no idea what have I been doing wrong.

I have a table "Beer" and I want to select all the data out with a stored procedure which I call out of Java app.

I have a java.class file Store_A.java which I have loaded into the ORACLE database with LOADJAVA :

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Store_a {

  public static void apskatit () 
    throws SQLException 
    { String sql = 
      "SELECT * FROM Beer";
    try { Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:"); 
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
      rset.close();
      pstmt.close(); 
      } 
    catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }  
  }
}
```

Then I have created a procedure which I plan to call out in java:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Store_a AS
PROCEDURE apskatit;
END Store_a;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Store_a AS
PROCEDURE apskatit AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Store_a.apskatit()';
END Store_a;
```

And I have a java file that I have created with JDeveloper 12c:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Class1 {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            //Izveidojam savienojumu
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.oracle.thin:@localhost:1521", "SYSTEM", "asdasd");
            // Izveidojam callable statement
            CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("CALL Store_a.apskatit()");
            ResultSet resul = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (resul.next()) {
                System.out.println(resul.getInt(1) + "\t" + resul.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the java file, I get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at client.Class1.main(Class1.java:29). The line I get error in is

```
conn.close();
```

How to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Another day, another Java exception without a stacktrace.  Your error message will tell you the exact class and line number where the exception is happening, so if you don't feel like reading it yourself and figuring out the error, you need to at least copy and paste the exact stack trace.

Comment: I am sorry, forgot to add it. Error at client.class1.main(Class.java:29)

Comment: I believe it's this line -    conn.close();

Answer (score 0):

If you get a NPE (null pointer exception) the reason is that your conn object is null. In your finally block you try to close the connection without checking if the connection is set at all.
I guess you have another exception before the NPE. Check you log output.